# I don't quite understand filtering in a Angular controller?

Tags: angularjs

I've read some Angular docs and have seen some examples but I'm still not clear how I can filter like I need to.

What I have is a API that will retrieve a list of records that have a status like Open, Closed, Pending, Urgent. The idea is that I would get all of the records back and send them to the page. I also get a list of those status' so they are populated in a dropdownlist. When the page loads I would like to display the Open records first and then switch to different record status when the user chooses one from the dropdownlist.

So, I get how you can sign an array of filtered items like `this.filteredArray = filterFilter(this.array, {status:'Open'});` but if I use that in my `ng-repeat` the other records won't be available because that array would only have the 'Open' records and nothing else....correct?

If I use an array with all of the records in it, which is currently about 415 records, then it will display all of them first and not do any filtering until someone selects from the dropdownlist.

I tried and example `<span ng-repeat="vm in ctrl.allRecordsArray | filter={status:'Open'}">{{vm.name}}</span>` but that didn't seem to work for me. Even if it did, I don't know how I would tie it to the dropdownlist for changing the data.

I'm sure someone has done something similar to this. I just can't find any examples.

**UPDATE**

In the debugger, I can see records returned from my database call (428 records). I can also see a property named “StatusName” and in this screen shot you can see it says “Closed”.  I’m filtering on Closed for testing because most of the initial records are in a “Closed” status.

[image]
If I use the following without any filtering then I get records to populate on the page.

```
<tr ng-repeat="call in vm.calls">
```

If I use the following to try to filter the data, nothing gets written out to the page.

```
<tr ng-repeat="call in vm.calls | filter={StatusName: 'Closed'}">
```

It looks like the code is correct so I’m lost as to why it doesn’t work. It’s almost like there is some kind of space or character in the object property value that is causing it to not match up and/or filter correctly.

I'm not sure that this plays into the issue just yet but just in case, here is my code for the dropdownlist.

```
    <select id="categoryId"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="vm.selectedCategory"
        ng-options="item.StatusName for item in vm.callStatus track by item.Id">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding from your question, you should use `dropdownlist model in your filtering` rather than using constant name

From :

```
<span ng-repeat="vm in ctrl.allRecordsArray | filter={status:'Open'}">
```

To :

```
<span ng-repeat="vm in ctrl.allRecordsArray | filter={status: your_dropdownlist_model}">
```

In this way, filtering would be based on your your_dropdownlist_model value. Whenever you change dropdownlist value, it would be automatically filtered according to changed value in dropdownlist.

Comment: That's starting to make more sense. I'm going give this a try and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I’m baffled as to why this isn’t working. Please look at my update in the main post to see if I’m missing something.

Comment: If your dropdownlist model binds by vm.statusName, then you should ng-repeat filtering should be `<span ng-repeat="vm in ctrl.allRecordsArray | filter={status: vm.statusName}">`

Comment: This doesn't make sense just yet either. "filter=" tells Angular to do a filter. The "{}" tells Angular to use an object to filter on. What does "status:" relate to? The object doesn't have a property named "status"? It also doesn't have "statusName" but it does have "StatusName". I get that vm is alias name for my control's array of data. Should it be filter={StatusName: vm.StatusName}? What does the "status:" above represent?

Comment: I think, you are taking it in complex way : status is the property name in your collection and statusName is your viewmodel used for binding dropdownlist value.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the filter its own model, and allow the user to change the model independently.

**[Here is a working plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/I1jEWiccpupsYmFIrnZM)**

In your view:

```
<button ng-click="currentStatus = ''">All</button>
<button ng-click="currentStatus = 'Open'">Open</button>
<button ng-click="currentStatus = 'Closed'">Closed</button>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="vm in items | filter: {status: currentStatus}">{{vm.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And in your controller:

```
  $scope.currentStatus = 'Open';
  $scope.items = [
  {'status': 'Open',
   'name': 'Open1'},
  {'status': 'Open',
   'name': 'Open2'},
  {'status': 'Open',
   'name': 'Open3'},
  {'status': 'Open',
   'name': 'Open1'},
  {'status': 'Closed',
   'name': 'Closed1'},
  {'status': 'Closed',
   'name': 'Closed2'},
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's makes some sense there. However, I think @LolCoder's example applies a little better to me in the fact that it is tied to a DDL and not button clicks.